# Removing a Directory if it exists

Tags: linux, shell, tcsh

I have a directory named **Directory_X** and I want to check if it exists. I want to remove it, if it exists and create another directory named **Directory_Y**. I tried the below code, it is showing if:Expression Syntax error

```
if [ -d "Directory_X" ]; then
rm -rf Directory_X
mkdir Directory_Y  
fi
```

Comment: That looks like sh syntax, not csh. I'd just use bash instead of tcsh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using POSIX sh syntax whereas your shell appears to be csh/tcsh. The [`if` statement](https://linux.die.net/man/1/csh) syntax is different for tsch:

```
if ( ! -d "Directory_X" ) then
    rm -rf Directory_X
    mkdir Directory_Y  
endif
```